# How can I Protect some pages through authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I have many pages in web application, i want display some pages to all including anonymous user and some pages should be protected from anonymous user can it is possible through authentication and authorization.. if it is possible then please tell me how......

Answer (score 1):

There is built in functionality in ASP.NET for this. See [ASP.NET Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd.aspx) on MSDN for an introduction.

You can specify what roles are allowed to access different pages/paths. With a membership and role provider you get a built in handling of users and roles. If you are in a corporate environment you probably want to integrate with Windows authentication, otherwise there is a good SqlMembership provider that handles all the user storage in the database in a secure way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep away from building an authentication system into your application you're best bet is to look at putting the pages that need protection into a separate directory on the webserver, then using : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html to protect them.

This of course assumes you're using apache.

It is no longer recommended to use the .htaccess files.